# Kraken API error "EFunding:Unknown withdraw key"

Tags: kraken.com

I'm currently using the Kraken API to make orders and withdraw currency.
The problem is when I want to withdraw EUR thanks to the Kraken API, they ask me to put my ithdrawal key name. I thought it was my API key or my key description, but none of these methods actually works.

```
 aclass = asset class (optional):

    currency (default)

 asset = asset being withdrawn

 key = withdrawal key name, as set up on your account

 amount = amount to withdraw, including fees
```

Where can I retrieve my withdrawal key name on my account ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"key = withdrawal key name, as set up on your account"

You must declare the addresses (send to), and assign a unique name (key) to each address.

I know... it's terrible.